# How to install urwfonts-8.71.tar.bz2 in Linux?

Tags: linux, fonts, installation, centos, centos5

I have downloaded this free set of 80 standard fonts, but I'm not sure how to install it in my Linux box (CentOS 5.4). Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: You would be much better off on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) with this question.

Comment: see, http://g33kinfo.com/info/archives/1806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [CentOS's font guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-x-fonts.html).

Basically, you unzip the fonts into `/usr/share/fonts/local` (creating the folder if necessary), then call `fc-cache /usr/share/fonts/local`.